# wrong arguments when passing params and class in text_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

currently I have a search field in my index page, and I am trying to pass the values for params and class, like this:

```
%div.form-group
   text_field_tag :from_date, 'Starts From Date...', params[:from_date], class: 'form-control'
```

However, I get the error:

> wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 1..3)

I have been searching for the right syntax but I couldn't find any. Moreover, I took a quick look at the rails API, and I see that the maximum arguments for the text_field_tag are 3, and I am passing 4 arguments right now. So, if anybody has solved this problem before, please enlighten me here. 
Thank you and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
text_field_tag :from_date, params[:from_date], class: 'form-control', placeholder:  'Starts From Date...'
```

The format is

```
text_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})
```

name is the field_name to ass in param, value what ever you want to give here you can give `params[:form_date]` or any string if you want you can give empty string "" or nil what you want the value

Comment: Thanks very much. Why could I forget about the placeholder attribute. You are a genius. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

```
%div.form-group
    =text_field_tag :from_date, params[:from_date].present? ? params[:from_date] : 'Starts From Date...', class: 'form-control'
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my questions. I want to display the custom name, and also get the params value in my form, not to pick one of them. Thank you anyway. Have a nice day.